# Error when call a controller in yii2 basic

Tags: php, yii2

i create a controller like this in folder controllers yii basic

```
 <?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;

class HelloController extends Controller
{

    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
    }

    public function actionPosts($id=0, $category="all")
    {
        echo "Sedang menampilkan postingan dengan id: ".$id;
    }

    public function actionPostComments($id)
    {
        echo "Sedang menampilkan komentar dari postingan dengan id: ".$id;
    }

    public function actionUserPosts($user_id, $bulan, $tahun)
    {
        echo "Sedang menampilkan daftar postingan dari user dengan id ".$user_id." dengan arsip ".$bulan." / ".$tahun;
    }
}
```

but when i try to call the function actionUserPosts with this link

http://localhost/hello-yii/web/index.php?r=hello/user-posts?user_id=10&bulan=2&tahun=2017

the result is Not Found (#404)

what's wrong with this?

Comment: object not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your Url like this

```
http://localhost/hello-yii/web/index.php?r=hello/userPosts&user_id=10&bulan=2&tahun=2017
```

? is use only first time when variable pass in url and then & sign.

Comment: if this answer helpful for you then please accept by clicking right sign.